# Stopping an Angular.$timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I tried stopping an angular.$timeout.
However, it isn't working as expected.

Checkout [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVRmzL) codepen for code

If you press the start, I expect the timer to stop at 0. However, it keeps going to negative.
However, if you press the "stop" button, it stops. Can anyone enlighten me on what I did wrong?

Code sample below:

```
$scope.countdown = function() {
    stopped = $timeout(function() {
      if($scope.counter == 0) {
        $scope.stop();
      }
       console.log($scope.counter);
     $scope.counter--;   
     $scope.countdown();   
    }, 1000);
  };


$scope.stop = function(){
   $timeout.cancel(stopped);

    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the counter reaches 0, you start by calling `$scope.stop()` in the `if` block. Then the rest of the function executes, and decrements the counter, calls `countdown()` again, recreating a new timeout.

Put the rest of the function in an `else` block, and you'll have the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just add return after `$scope.stop()` to break out of the function, so the timer won't start again.

```
$scope.countdown = function() {
    stopped = $timeout(function() {
      console.log($scope.counter);
      if($scope.counter == 0) {
        $scope.stop();
        return; // <-- break out of the function
      }
       console.log($scope.counter);
     $scope.counter--;   
     $scope.countdown();   
    }, 1000);
  };
```

Comment: For some reason, when I did this, the countdown still continued.

Comment: It seems to be. I guess there must be something wrong on my side.
I am sorry I can't give you as answer as I have already selected Nizet's. I'll give you a upvote instead. :)
Thanks again

Comment: Yey - bronze medal :-p